# Jquery css property not working for second time

Tags: jquery, ajax

My target is to display spinning image during the AJAX call, but its working for first ajax call but the code calls subsequent ajax calls based on page scroll down but spinning image is not working for subsequent calls, alerts are working for subsequent calls only displaying spinning image is not working.

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    alert(1);
        $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    alert(2);
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
    }); 

<div id="wait" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse  fa-5x"></i></div>
```

Comment: I suspect it is hidden behind other content (due to the absolute positioning).

Comment: try to add. z-index:99999 in #wait

Comment: Thank  you for quick response, its working after removing position, top, left attributes but its displaying below footer which is not visible to user. so how can we fix this.?

Comment: its working after changing position from absolute to fixed. Thanks.